# Batch file: input barcodes string substitution

Tags: batch-file, input, user-input, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am using batch script and I have an input variable like this:

```
~zon|123456789~~zln|12~
```

Once entered, I am getting this message: "| was unexpected at this time."

How should I use string substitution to have an output result as below:

```
123456789-12
```

I try to use this one but it does not work.
Using on Date format is good though.
Do you have any idea?

```
set path=~zon|123456789~~zln|12~
echo the variable is "%path:~4,8%" 
pause
```

Output:

> C:>set path=~zon|123456789~~zln|12~
>
> '23897975~~mln' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Because `|` is a redirection command and is with higher prio than set - so you you have to use quotes like bellow.
It is not good idea to set your variable with name `path` as there's such  windows environment variable. You can use for to split the string by `~` and `|`:

```
set "p=~zon|123456789~~zln|12~"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|~" %%a in ("%p%") do echo %%a
```

with sub-string:

```
echo "%p:~5,9%"
```

**EDIT:**

to get the two other digits:

```
set "p=~zon|EightDigits~~zln|OneOrTwoDigits~"
for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=|~" %%a in ("%p%") do echo %%a-%%b
```

Comment: Great. The current output is 123456789.

There are cases the "12" from ~zon|123456789~~zln|12~ whereby it can be one or two digits. 
How should i write in order to get this output?

123456789-12 (Last two digits after "-")
123456789-8 (Last one digit after "-")

Comment: The format of the barcode is ~zon|EightDigits~~zln|OneOrTwoDigits~

Comment: that did the trick. Thanks. I do have next step to go which replied at Stephan. Glad to have your ideas.

Comment: @virtualixer if you want to check if `%%a-%%b` are empty you can use `if %%a-%%b equ -`

Comment: it just bypass the whole IF statement line when i try. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is the source. Which area that i miss out? echo off :menu SET order=none SET id=none set /p order=Please scan the Order: for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=|~" %%a in ("%order%") do set code=%%a-%%b if "%code%" =="-" echo Empty Input & GOTO:menu echo **************************************************************** set /p id=Please enter your ID: IF %id% EQU none (((ECHO.) & ECHO You should not leave it empty!) & (ECHO.) & PAUSE &GOTO:menu) echo **************************************************************** @echo %code% %id% >> "C:\Record.txt" echo Done

Answer (score 2):

```
set "p=~zon|123456789~~zln|12~"
for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=|~" %%a in ("%p%") do echo %%a-%%b
```

Tokenization goes like this:

```
~zon|123456789~~zln|12~
# 1 #    2    ## 3 #4 #
```

`#` = delimiter; consecutive delimiters are treated as one. If the very first char is a delimiter, it is ignored.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I have another one.

How should i pass the string %%a-%%b to do the IF statement like below?

IF %%a-%%b EQU none (
   ((ECHO.) & ECHO You should not leave it empty!) & (ECHO.) & PAUSE & GOTO:menu
)
ELSE 
(@ECHO %%a-%%b %date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%>> C:\tokenized.txt
)

Comment: the resulting string is at least a dash - because we added that explicitely. So test `if "%%a-%%b" =="-" echo empty input`

Comment: it just bypass the whole IF statement line when i try. Any thoughts?

Comment: replace `echo %%a-%%b` with `set code=%%a-%%b`. The `for` variables (`%%x`) are not defined any more, when `for` finishes. Then `if "%code%" =="-" ...`

Comment: It's still bypassing the IF statement. Here is the source. Which area that i miss out?
echo off
:menu
SET order=none
SET id=none
set /p order=Please scan the Order:
for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=|~" %%a in ("%order%") do set code=%%a-%%b
if "%code%" =="-" echo Empty Input & GOTO:menu
echo ****************************************************************
set /p id=Please enter your ID:
IF %id% EQU none (((ECHO.) & ECHO You should not leave it empty!) & (ECHO.) & PAUSE &GOTO:menu)
echo ****************************************************************
@echo %code% %id% >> "C:\Record.txt"
echo Done

Comment: There is nothing in the code to "bypass". Run it with `echo on` instead of  `echo off` to see, what happens. Probably replacing `set order=none` with `set "order=-"` helps. Also `echo "#%order%#"` after scanning might be a good idea to check it's content.

Comment: i managed to run through the IF statement. Any idea if i would like to have an auto "Enter" key after input the %code%, and straight away go to %id%. How should i achieve that?

Comment: there are possibilities, but they are ugly and hard to implement. A better way would be to configure your scanner to send "Enter". Read the manual first. If that doesn't help, please ask a new question for that.